# Is it possible to implement two web services data into a single table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In this i had implemented using two table views i need it to implement it in a single table view is it possible or not if possible then can anyone help me how to implement and in this i got the required output but i was trying to implement it on single table view so that the spacing between two table views was more during landscape so that in order to avoid this i was trying to implement this any help would be of great appreciation

```
  let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bMlqRPbjGW?indent=2"
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVWKKHtWbm?indent=2"
    var shippingArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
    var keys = [String]()
    let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
    var arrayss =  [String:Any]()
    var checkIsRadioSelect = [Int]()
    var checkIsButtonEnable = [Int]()
    var checkIsPaymentRadioSelect = [Int]()
    let response : [Int] = []
    var chekIndex:IndexPath?
    var selected: Bool = false
    var dataArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableDetails.isHidden = true
        shippingTableView.isHidden = true
        titleLabel.isHidden = true
        newAddress.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        continueButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        myActivityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 320, width: 30, height: 30)
        myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
        myActivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
        self.shippingaddressURL()
        self.shippingmethodURL()
        tableDetails.delegate = self
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        shippingTableView.delegate = self
        shippingTableView.dataSource = self
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: 400)
//        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableDetails.frame.size.width, height: 50))
//        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
//        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 280, height: 30))
//        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
//        button.setTitle("Create a New Addresss", for: .normal)
//        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
//        tableDetails.tableFooterView = customView
//        customView.addSubview(button)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
    }
    func shippingaddressURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    let height = (self.shippingArray.count * 165)
                    print(self.shippingArray.count)
                    self.heightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height)
//                    print(height)
//                    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: (CGFloat(height) + 28 + 28))
//                    print(self.scrollView.contentSize)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func shippingmethodURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(self.arrayss)
                self.keys = jsonObj?.allKeys as! [String]
                print(self.keys)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
                    let height = self.arrayss.count * 115
                    print(self.arrayss.count)
                    self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height)
                    print(height)
                    print(self.heightConstraint.constant)
                    print(self.scrollView.contentSize)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {
            shippingTableView.isHidden = false
            titleLabel.isHidden = false
            let height = self.arrayss.count * 115
             self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: CGFloat(self.heightConstraint.constant + 56) + CGFloat(height + 31 + 56 + 28 + 28))
        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func paymentRadioAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let center = sender.center;
        let centralPOint = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to:self.shippingTableView )
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPOint!)

        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            selected = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        var count = 0
        if tableView.tag == 100{
            return 1
        }
        else if tableView.tag == 110 {
            return arrayss.count
        }
        return count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if tableView.tag == 100{
            return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
        }
        else  {
            return self.keys[section]
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        if tableView.tag == 100 {
            let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
            header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
        }
        else {
            let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
            header.tintColor = UIColor.white
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
            header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
            header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if tableView.tag == 100{
            return shippingArray.count
        }
        else {
            let key = self.keys[section]
            let a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
            return a.count
        }
    }
    @IBAction func continueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if selected == false{
            let radiobutton = SCLAlertView()
            _ =  radiobutton.showError("Warning", subTitle: "Please select shipping method", closeButtonTitle: "OK")

        }else{
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "payment") as! PaymentMethodViewController
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        shippingArray.remove(at:sender.tag)
        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView.tag == 100{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Any =  arr["number"] as AnyObject
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\(mobilenumber)"
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                shippingTableView.isHidden = false
                tableDetails.isScrollEnabled = false
                scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
                titleLabel.isHidden = false
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
            let key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
            var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
            var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
            let name = dictionary["name"]
            let price = dictionary ["price"]
            cell.methodNameLabel.text = name  as? String
            cell.priceLabel.text = price as? String
            if chekIndex == indexPath {
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            } else {
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [Dispatch Queues to call multiple webservices](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2017/06/calling-depending-web-services.html)

Comment: is it possible to implement just see my second table view data and then tell  me bro @pkc456

Comment: this site was not opening @pkc456

Comment: Try now to open link.

Comment: but i don't need this one i need to implement two table views data into a single table view @pkc456

Comment: You can take one tableview and can create multiple cell for every type of your content like payment view, cart view etc. You can use multiple section also as per requirement.

Comment: how to give no. of sections when using single table view ? @luckyShubhra

Comment: using numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: i am asking in my case how to give no. of sections count @luckyShubhra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your logic as

1. Let A and B be retrieved json data from your 1st and 2 second url respectively.
2. Add A and B in an array. Say dataArray = [A,B]
3. in numberOfSections return dataArray.count
4. in numberOfRowsInSection return dataArray[section].count
5. Lastly you can create multiple custom cell and use them in tableview accordingly as

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   switch(indexPath.section)  {
   case 0:{
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
           return cell 
          }
   case 1:{
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
           return cell 
          }
   Default:{
           //Default settings
          }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: one data array is [string: anyObject] and second data array is [[String : anyObject]] how to add this both @luckyShubhra

Comment: you can use generic array for the same. var dataArray :[Any] = []  , and append A and B values in dataArray.

Comment: Any help how to implement this ? @luckyShubhra

Comment: dont apend data in numberofsections. After you get data from both api i.e. A, B add them to dataArray and thenceforth reload tableview. In in numberOfSections 'return dataArray.count'

Comment: i didn't understand what ur saying ? @luckyShubhra

Comment: Declare var dataArray :[Any] = [] .In viewDidLoad after calling self.shippingaddressURL()
        self.shippingmethodURL() add shippingArray and arrayss in dataArray and use dataArray.

Comment: if i add in view did load also i was getting same error as shown above @luckyShubhra

Comment: bro can i send my project so that u can check whats wrong in that @luckyShubhra

Comment: i had sent my project please check and help me bro @luckyShubhra

Comment: I will check once I reach my place and let u know. I would appreciate if you accept my ans. It would be helpful in case some one requires the same. Accepting ans earns reputation for you as well as the person who answered .

Comment: sure bro sorry i forgot @luckyShubhra

Comment: bro have u checked my project ? @luckyShubhra

Comment: kk bro @luckyShubhra

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148999/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-luckyshubhra).

Comment: hello bro have u checked my project ? @luckyShubhra

Answer (score 0):

Just create two function inside your custom tableviewCell ie. `loadDataOne(data:JSON)` and `loadDataTwo(data:JSON)` and call these method as in Your Custom TableViewCell

```
var dataOne:JSON!{
        didSet{
            loadDataOne()
        }
    }
```